# How is this null terminated?

Tags: c

I am aware when using char arrays you must initialise the size to at the length of the string + 1 to account for `\0`

But if I don't account for `\0` how does strchr claim that `\0` Is in the char array since this prints *"is null terminated"*

```
char mark[4] = "mark";
if(strchr(mark, '\0')) {
    puts("Is null terminated.");
} else {
    puts("Is not");
}
```

Comment: `memchr(mark, 0, sizeof mark)` instead of `strchr(mark, '\0')`

Comment: using `strchr` on a non null-terminated string is undefined behavior, as it will keep searching until it finds a null. In other words it will keep happy zipping through memory until it either segfaults or finds a null

Comment: There is *no guarantee* what value is at `mark[4]`.  If it ***happens*** to be `\0`, then you got lucky.  But that is not reliable.  If there is not a terminator at `mark[4]`, there will be one *eventually* by sheer accident *(maybe at `mark[245]`??)* Or you'll eventually hit an "Invalid Memory Access" situation.

Comment: You should get a compiler warning as your array is 4 chars long but you need 5, one more for the NUL terminator.

Comment: @MichaelWalz no warnings here! - im using clang with -Wall -Wextra

Comment: Why downvote? At least mention how to improve the question.

Comment: @Mark: A not null-terminates character array is not a string! C has no string type and that's exactly the convention.

Comment: @Olaf I didn't mean string type! I just meant the length of the word!

Comment: Read about the implications of _undefined behaviour_.

Comment: @Mark: If I was not clear enough: A character array without null-termination is **not a C-string**. `strchr` and the other string functions expect a **C-string**. If you don't pass a C-string, you violate the convention, invoking undefined behaviour. As you seem to be aware of this, it is not clear what your problem is. You intentionally violate the rules, so what do you expect?

Comment: Sidenote: the null-terminator is not part of the string contents. `strchr` is expected to search string contents, your usage is pointless for this reason, too (in addition to the one I gave ^).

Comment: @Mark strange, on [https://godbolt.org/](https://godbolt.org/) I get `error: initializer-string for char array is too long` with clang.

Comment: @Olaf actually I didn't know that, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @rici: Why would I, as you already did? No need for side blows.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: C is not C++, and the rules for initializing character arrays differ between the two languages. In C, if you don't leave enough room for the NUL, the compiler assumes you meant to create a non NUL-terminated array. In C++, it's an error. But this question is tagged [tag:c].

Comment: @rici right, I didn't notice at first that godbolt has only c++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strchr` isn't limited to, or even aware of, the length of the array you're passing to it, so will continue on throughout the rest of memory until it finds what it is looking for.

If you print the value returned by `strchr` you'll see that it is beyond the end of the array.

Comment: I just get an empty line after changing it to `if((p = strchr(mark, '\0'))) {
  printf("%s\n", p);
 }`

Comment: @Mark: As you should have; `p` points to a null byte, after all.

Comment: @Mark use `%p` not `%s`, you want the pointer value, not the string value

Answer (score 0):

```
char mark[4] = "mark";
```

This line above can be divided in two:

```
char mark[4];
sprintf(mark,"mark");
```

The first line is reserving 4 bytes in the memory, and the mark name will return the address of the first byte.

And the second line (which is equivalent to mark = "mark", but writing during the execution) is writing the string "mark" to the memory, starting at the address named mark, the problem here is that how you are writting a string you will write 5 bytes, so you will write the 4 characters in the 4 bytes reserved to the variable AND will write a NULL (0x00) to the 5th byte, which doesn't belong to the variable!

if you have another variable allocated right after the mark variable, you probably will corrupt it when you write the string, as it will invade this variable address and overwrite it.